# Push data into array - Error: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays, object

I'm trying to figure out how to push multiple values into array object.

```
var fileCount = 0;
var limboData = []; //trying to store values in array to create a table

function XgetAllSites(){
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
    async: false,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status){
      site = $(xData.responseXML);
      site.find('Web').each(function(){
        //var siteName = $(this).attr('Title');
        var siteUrl = $(this).attr('Url');
        Xgetlists(siteUrl);
        console.log("At All Sites Level"); //check point
      });
    }
  });
}
function Xgetlists(siteUrl){
    $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetListCollection",
      webURL: siteUrl,
      async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status){
          $(xData.responseXML).find("List[ServerTemplate='101']").each(function(){
            var listId = $(this).attr('ID');
            XgetListItems(listId, siteUrl)
            console.log("At site list"); //check point
          });
        }
    });
}
function XgetListItems(listId, siteUrl){
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    webURL: siteUrl,
    listName: listId,
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
    CAMLQuery: '<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="_UIVersionString" /><Value Type="Text">1.0</Value></Eq><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser" /></IsNotNull></And></Where></Query>',
    async: false,
    completefunc: function (xData,Status){
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {   
          var fileName = $(this).attr('ows_LinkFilename');
          var fileUrl = $(this).attr('ows_FileDirRef');
          var checkedTo = $(this).attr('ows_LinkCheckedOutTile');
          var modified = $(this).attr('ows_Modifiedff');

          limboData[fileCount].push({fileName: fileName, fileUrl:fileUrl,checkedTo:checkedTo,modified:modified}); //trying to store information from returned values in array using fileCount as the index
          fileCount++;
          console.log("At list items. File Count: "+fileCount);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value of the array at the index `limboData[fileCount]` is `undefined` until it's been set, so you can't use:

```
limboData[fileCount].push(...);
```

Instead, you can set the value either by using the index:

```
limboData[fileCount] = { 
    fileName: fileName, 
    fileUrl:fileUrl, 
    checkedTo:checkedTo, 
    modified:modified 
};
```

Or by simply calling `push`:

```
limboData.push({
    fileName: fileName, 
    fileUrl:fileUrl, 
    checkedTo:checkedTo, 
    modified:modified
});
```